# Arduino Atmega2560 double Inaccuracy

Tags: arduino, double, compiler-optimization, floating-accuracy, atmega

Double-precision numbers are commonly inaccurate at the 3 last digits (beyond 11th decimal - mantissa)

But within Arduino Mega / Atmega2560 the round error is very soon, at 7th decimal. Even with constants.

```
#include <math.h>

Serial.println(M_PI,14);
//3.14159274101257

double s_pi = 3.14159265358979d; // or trunc like 3.14159263 ,  3.14159264... same result
Serial.println(s_pi,14);
//3.14159274101257
```

It feels like the compiler convert everything in `float` instead of `double`

How to fix that ?

Comment: On ATMEGA based Arduinos `float` and [`double`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double) are the same size (4 bytes).

Comment: Uh, my bad, I thought it was ATMEGA that has 8 bytes floating point but it is  the Arduino Due .. The doc was misleading .